# Gradle and including images

Tags: java, gradle, png

Everything compiles fine when i run gradle except for images. I don't know where I'm doing wrong...

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    resources {
      srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
      includes = ["**/*.png"]
includes = ["**/*.css"]
}
}
}

dependencies {
 compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
 }

task(run, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
   main = 'Main'
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
 }
```

Comment: Why do you specify images in gradle? You can put them in assets folder or res/drawable-hdpi folders,etc. Without having to specify them in gradle.

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode it's not an Android app

Comment: What is exactly the issue ?

Comment: Why would you want to put images in a folder named `src/main/java`? That's for java files only. Resources including xml, property files and images etc should go in `src/main/resources`